# how to store json data into the database from api in php by curl get?

Tags: php, json, curl

the code is as below...

```
$url = 'http://tools.vcommission.com/api/coupons.php?apikey=a7f66abd541c5667ebb8b234f6345df00dbc5dc856d8e7bcd02bb6d636f902fc';
$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$data = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

echo $data;
```

This is the actual code,,, i need to get the json data and store it in the database.

Comment: Please edit the question and show what have you trie so far and what doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code

```
$data = curl_exec($ch);    
curl_close($ch);   
$json = json_decode($data , true);
```

then your SQL insert functionality , go through this link http://www.kodingmadesimple.com/2014/12/how-to-insert-json-data-into-mysql-php.html

Comment: but there is an error as below...      Undefined index: featured in C:\xampp\htdocs\vcm\index.php on line 27... please help me about this...

Comment: " Undefined index: featured" in $json = json_decode($data , true); ?   or when you are inserting record ?

Comment: can i get ur mail id please